# add numeric numbers with text value automatic in excle

Tags: excel

Hi i have a sheet which have duplicate values in text. I just want to add numeric number series so it make value unique. for ex:

```
Cell A  | Cell B  | Cell C (result)
=============================
My Name |   this  | My Name 1
-------------------------------
my Name | you      | My Name 2
My name |  our     |  My name 3
```

In cell C i want cell A values with numeric numbers . I hope you understand my question thanks.

Comment: Can they be *any* number? You could just add the row number no? In column C, use `=A2&" "&row()`

Comment: @BruceWayne  thanks its work ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would adding the row number to your text in column A work?

```
=A1&" "&row(A1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following formula works even if your column A is not sorted or if you have multiple duplicates.

```
=A1 & " " & COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)
```